camera not found in Ubuntu 24.04
My camera app is showing device not found. I tried installing cheese but I got the same problem. I tried many solutions but none of them worked.

What have you tried? Please edit the question and add what you have tried and all errors or messages you got. If one app says device not found I would expect others to do the same.

Please add more details about your device

When you "tried many solutions" did you take care to undo each failed solution as you went along, or did you pile failure atop failure, leading to a "stirred with a root stick" example of an unsupportable system? Please [edit] your Question, and tell us what you did.
